# Error installing r2corba on ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, corba

This may or may not be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647717/error-installing-r2corba-on-jruby where I'm describing a similar problem on jruby.

This time I'm using ruby 1.9.3. When trying to install r2corba I get the following:

```
Installing r2corba (1.4.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby mkrf_conf_srcgem.rb 
Failed to install taosource gem.
Gem sources: ["http://rubygems.org/"]


Gem files will remain installed in /home/tomasz/.bundler/tmp/16489/gems/r2corba-1.4.1   for inspection.
Results logged to /home/tomasz/.bundler/tmp/16489/gems/r2corba-1.4.1/./gem_make.out
An error occured while installing r2corba (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install r2corba -v '1.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: This looks like you are using bundler. What happens when you follow the instructions and run `gem install r2corba -v '1.4.1'` in the command line? (maybe you just need to run as sudo). Also it helps if you post the commands you use with such questions.

Comment: I tried both through the bundler and direct gem and get the same error.

Comment: Update: I ran "gem install taosource", which appears to be a precondition for r2corba and it's been running for awhile building native extensions. We'll see how it goes.